# make taxonomy terms more human friendly

Tags: path-aliases

I work on a  news site that has hundreds of articles and all the article urls are written by hand. eg. example.com/world-news-today-28-march-2018
The site has various news categories like: business, economy, technology, etc
but they are named taxonomy/term/1 and so on.
Is it too late now to activate pathauto module on a live production site that has tons of content?
All I want to do is change the urls of the news categories and make them more human friendly, so example.com/taxonomy/term/1 becomes example.com/business
without touching the article urls which are in each category.
Any ideas how can I do this and if it's safe at this stage?

Comment: You can add Pathauto and Redirect module so it creates redirects from URLs when new ones are generated.

Comment: Why you are considering Pathauto? You've written the url aliases for the nodes by hand, why not do the same for the taxonomy terms? As soon as you enter a url alias in the term edit form the internal path taxonomy/term/1 will be replaced.

Comment: Thank you, I entered a url alias in the term edit form the internal path like you said and it worked like a charm. A million thanks again, and I wish you Happy Holiday.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module and follow these steps:

- Enable pathauto module
- Go to `admin/config/search/path/patterns` and set the patterns for specific taxonomy using [Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token) module and save the form
- Go to `admin/config/search/path/update_bulk` and generate URLs for taxonomy

Don't worry about the existing URLs (no matter wherever you added it) it will remain same, [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) will not effect anything. Now, visitors can access by both URLs (default and newly generated).

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I chose the manual way to avoid installing extra modules, because the site has too many already. Thanks again.